# What formula does SPSS apply to the data in an ANCOVA? Or exactly *how* does ANCOVA adjust the dependent variable?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, anova, spss, ancova

The procedure for an ANOVA is really straightforward; you compute the between group variance and the within group variance, divide your results to get an F statistic, and compare it to your critical value.

But what about ANCOVA? I can't find an exact procedure anywhere. Can someone show me a piece of code to find the F statistic in an ANCOVA? And not just using pre-built ANCOVA modules, because what I am interested in is how the resulting F statistic is obtained.

I tried researching the ANCOVA formula, but to no avail. Everyone online just says "computation would be tedious and just use a software" but never actually explain the procedure.

Comment: The "exact procedure" is called *Ordinary Least Squares Regression.*  Here's [a site search:](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=hascode%3Atrue+lm) you will appreciate the number of hits ;-).  Less facetiously, adding "ANCOVA" to the search [looks truly helpful](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=hascode%3Atrue+lm+ANCOVA).

Comment: Thank you so much! If you can write a detailed answer for me, I will award it with a bounty when I reach 75 rep.